# How many levels of Cache for a Joomla Page

Tags: google-chrome, caching, joomla

Whenever I change something on a Joomla page, like an image, CSS, or whatever, I have to refresh the page in Chrome with ctrl-shift-r.

I'd like to disable any cache, so that I don't have to do that.

How many cache places do I need to disable?

1. server cache
2. joomla cache
3. browser cache

?, do I have to disable the browser cache aswell?

..or can I set a timeout on all items?

Any pointers as to what I can try?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the only issue that you're having is the browser cache. Try adding the following to your .htaccess file:

```
ExpiresActive Off
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
Header unset Pragma
Header unset Cache-Control
Header unset Last-Modified
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Expires "Tue, 1 Jan 2019 00:00:00 GMT"
```

This should do it.